# Strange gulp "Directory does not exist" error?

Tags: gulp

I have checked out a repo, run `npm install` and tried to run `Gulp` but I get this error:

> [16:33:00] Directory "/Users/myname/project/folder/web/js-tasks" does
>   not exist.

If in the terminal I go `cd /Users/myname/project/folder/web/js-tasks` then it takes me to that directory with no problem. Ive tried running the gulp task as sudo incase its permission but I get the same result.

The `gulpfile.js` is at `~project/folder/web`. I am on a mac and I am using `Vagrant`. I am trying to run this from the host machine but if I SSH into my `Vagrant` machine, cd to where the `gulpfile.js` is and run gulp log I get a similar error `Directory "/web/js-tasks" does not exist.`

Comment: Can you share your `gulpfile.js` with us?

Comment: @ColinMarshall sorry about this but I cant recreate it now. This issue has come and gone more than once without me changing anything. Ill post back if im able to recreate it.

Answer (score 4):

Many times when I faced problems with gulp scripts - I use WebStorm IDE to debug them.

Fortunately WebStorm have debug feature for gulp tasks.

After you set breakpoint in your gulpfile.js, you need to:

1. Open Gulp panel in WebStorm
2. Right click on task you need to debug
3. Click "Debug ..." in context menu
4. When debugger stops on breakpoint you can manually check how Gulp "see" your file system by evaluating JS expression fs.readdirSync("/Users/myname/project/folder/web/js-tasks") in "Watches" panel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "fs is not defined"

Comment: @StingyJack add "var fs = require('fs');" at the start of your evaluated expression

Answer (score -1):

It turns out whenever there is any error in the gulp file that stops it running then I get this message instead of a proper error message.

Comment: You could still post your gulpfile so we could try to fix the error handling.